# Why does the Python3 ipaddress.IPv6Network.hosts function omit the first and last IPv6 address?

Tags: python, networking, python-3.x, ipv6

I noticed that the first and last IPv6 addresses of a given network are omitted:

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Sep  6 2013, 09:30:10) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ipaddress
>>> print("\n".join([str(x) for x in ipaddress.ip_network("2001:0db8::/120").hosts()]))
2001:db8::1
2001:db8::2
...
2001:db8::fe
>>> 
>>> hex(int(ipaddress.ip_address('2001:db8::fe')))
'0x20010db80000000000000000000000fe'
```

I believe that for IPv4 this is correct, as those represent the network and broadcast addresses, but I don't believe those exist in IPv6 - at least [section-2.5.4 of RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.4) doesn't seem to mention it. I checked the errata and I don't think the updating RFCs are relevant. The section on [interface identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.1) also doesn't appear to reserve the first/last addresses.

Does anyone know why these addresses are omitted? Is this a bug in the standard library?

EDIT:
Ok, looks like the first address is a [Subnet-Router anycast address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2373#section-2.6.1), so that explains why the first address is omitted.

The last address could be a [reserved anycast address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2526), though so is for example `2001:db8::fe/120` (which you can find in the output above), so this is certainly handled inconsistently. Does anybody know why?

Comment: That is a bug in `ipaddress`. The code still mentions network and broadcast addresses, but they don't exist anymore in IPv6.

Comment: Also `/120` is very non-standard and you should avoid subnetting any smaller than `/64`.

Comment: Good point - in this particular case I just wanted to get to the end of the output within a reasonable amount of time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in [the `ipaddress` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress), as unlike IPv4, both the first and last addresses in an IPv6 subnet are valid and usable, though they may have *special* uses as you've noted.

A quick survey of Python's bug tracker [doesn't turn up this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue?@columns=id,activity,title,creator,assignee,status,type&@sort=-activity&@filter=status&@action=searchid&ignore=file%3acontent&@search_text=ipaddress&submit=search&status=-1,1,2,3), so your next step should be to file a bug report on it.